# How Can I use shorthand?

Tags: javascript

My if blocks is very long. I want use shorthand. how can i do ?

```
     if (selected.value == "" || search.value == "") {
        data;
      } else if (selected.value == "Email") {
        data["email"] = search.value;
      } else if (selected.value == "Name") {
        data["name"] = search.value;
      } else if (selected.value == "Surname") {
        data["surname"] = search.value;
      }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: the question needs a lot of work before it would be appropriate for [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks, noted. I wasn't aware of the specific differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if (search.value && ["Email", "Name", "Surname"].includes(selected.value)) {
    data[selected.value.toLowerCase()]  = search.value;
}
```